# Panel regression errors

Tags: r, regression, tapply

I am trying to do the panel regression, where dependent variable (stock returns for various companies) is regressed on 5 independent variables. 
Here is the reproductible example of a data frame of independent variables

```
dput(factors_1[1:10,])
structure(list(Date = 200002:200011, Mkt.RF = c(5.94, 0.66, -5.58, 
-0.09, 0.67, -1.58, -1.61, -4.99, -2.71, -4.55), SMB = c(0.84, 
-5.15, -4.62, 0.16, 0.33, -0.69, 0.68, 2.35, -6.1, -0.78), HML = c(-9.45, 
3.33, 5.93, 6.17, 3.14, 3.31, -0.5, 2.64, 7.54, 11.15), RMW = c(3.55, 
-2.59, -1.53, -3.38, -3.45, -0.12, -1.27, 1.63, 2.7, 0.79), CMA = c(-7.33, 
4.96, 1.32, 4.94, 1.22, -0.12, 0.64, 2.16, 4.1, 8.75), RF = c(0.43, 
0.47, 0.46, 0.5, 0.4, 0.48, 0.5, 0.51, 0.56, 0.51)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

and here for the stock returns

```
dput(xx[1:10, 1:10])
structure(list(Date = structure(c(10990.9954886386, 11019.9953776753, 
11050.9954014418, 11080.9952984982, 11111.9953776753, 11141.9951640545, 
11172.995061378, 11203.9951324494, 11233.9950455918, 11264.9949982497
), class = "Date"), X1 = c(0.0954887438827963, 
-0.0596463008222008, 0.071350885788402, 0.0305926490738153, 0.0408331711459304, 
-0.0211402933162625, -0.00493862203119688, 0.006182173191563, 
0.0032423131269943, 0.0193884936176278), X2 = c(-0.123462974283698, 
0.230503533400868, -0.0272942506612435, 0.0483790669291113, -0.0595278152717571, 
0.12087834022411, -0.032011380068422, -0.0813892896957779, 0.0138779835292666, 
0.0726322608057619), X3 = c(-0.0682052985267971, 0.172249290323711, 
-0.154888201350603, 0.0395159403332963, -0.0143942598523314, 
-0.0607566985291722, -0.0310708779173386, -0.0746345858888015, 
-0.151109426840925, 0.0118888362760825), X4 = c(-0.114511361380472, 
0.00998441685033158, 0.192522150537581, -0.0158023343537101, 
0.0374730915541921, 0.0777493327863055, -0.0016218724457906, 
-0.0635452365157563, 0.0565030106039299, 0.115759209185826), 
   X5 = c(0.00389199996406542, -0.0212889913893688, 
    0.164892967212694, -0.00832469019706505, -0.00462232472270219, 
    -0.0070177636719938, 0.00453659662769512, 0.0528941822866427, 
    -0.00836737746775751, -0.0050017502848112), X6 = c(-0.10351479457366, 
    0.0237125822002096, 0.0101860439504515, 0.0111924296807739, 
    -0.0652473862813747, 2.11404059631271e-05, 0.0261396151198399, 
    -0.0356789492292369, -0.0706069184275196, -0.0656535040135704
    ), X7 = c(-0.0980023956049211, 0.102552120231041, 
    -0.0959174074104425, -0.0790740833989735, 0.118610740782993, 
    -0.100050822390369, -0.00333557692764708, -0.0368703292701125, 
    0.0628135821343774, 0.0471186471744018), X9 = c(-0.0304322345046196, 
    -0.0977595796246631, 0.138258584646108, 0.0344876873979214, 
    -0.000721154371596811, 0.0508635363751093, 0.0533435865577603, 
    -0.0506646520146184, 0.0497235991059199, 0.0284083879640369
    ), X9 = c(-0.159712703662352, -0.0234902492510041, 0.116858931667507, 
    0.00432376896685471, 0.114340108193219, 0.00235829911414087, 
    -0.0573195744121493, 0.095634961997471, -0.0871461890063988, 
    -0.0738243041819919)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I tried:

```
p1_q1_l<-plm(as.matrix(data.frame(xx[, -1]))~factors_1$Mkt.RF+factors_1$SMB+factors_1$HML+factors_1$RMW+factors_1$CMA,data=factors_1, method="within")
```

And what I got

```
Error in tapply(x, effect, func, ...) : arguments must have same length
```

I dont understand what is going on. Both tables are data frames with the same number of observations. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you're passing a data frame to the `data` parameter of a model, the formula should be of raw column names, e.g. `lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)`. Subsetting in a formula can cause strange things to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that the error arises from the fact that you define a matrix as your independent (Y) variable, where a vector is needed. You need the data in long format, where your Y is *one*  column, and an *ID* and a *time* column denotes the different observations.

I have some doubts about the compatibility of your two data sets, though, but you may want to merge them into one. Just carefully look, how you may merge your original data, particularly regarding the `Date` columns.

When I understand your `xxx` data right, the `X*` are the different firms. Now convert the data in long format, using `reshape`.

```
xxx <- reshape(xx, timevar=1, varying=2:9, direction="long", sep="")
xxx$Date <- as.character(xx$Date[xxx$Date])
```

Then, it might be easier to `merge` the two data sets into one. The `"Date"` columns of both data frames, however, don' t match. When I understand your `factors_1` data right, they are monthly values. I'll continue by simply attaching a `"03"` to the second to get them to match for now, but you know what's actually needed.

```
factors_1x <- transform(factors_1, 
                        Date=as.character(as.Date(strptime(paste(factors_1$Date, 03),
                                                           "%Y%m%d"))))
```

Here merge.

```
dat <- merge(xxx, factors_1x, all.x=TRUE)
head(dat)
#         Date           X id Mkt.RF  SMB   HML  RMW   CMA   RF
# 1 2000-02-03  0.09548874  1   5.94 0.84 -9.45 3.55 -7.33 0.43
# 2 2000-02-03 -0.05964630  2   5.94 0.84 -9.45 3.55 -7.33 0.43
# 3 2000-02-03  0.07135089  3   5.94 0.84 -9.45 3.55 -7.33 0.43
# 4 2000-02-03  0.03059265  4   5.94 0.84 -9.45 3.55 -7.33 0.43
# 5 2000-02-03  0.04083317  5   5.94 0.84 -9.45 3.55 -7.33 0.43
# 6 2000-02-03 -0.02114029  6   5.94 0.84 -9.45 3.55 -7.33 0.43
```

Now it is easier to write the formula. The new indices may be formulated in the `plm` call using `index=c("id", "Date")`.

```
library(plm)
p1_q1_l <- plm(X ~ Mkt.RF + SMB + HML + RMW + CMA + RF, method="within",
               index=c("id", "Date"), data=dat)
# Model Formula: X ~ Mkt.RF + SMB + HML + RMW + CMA + RF
# 
# Coefficients:
#     Mkt.RF        SMB        HML        RMW        CMA         RF 
#  0.0042267  0.0054278 -0.0016806  0.0129446  0.0148160 -0.4194726
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask why it does not work for the whole sample? I tried ```xxx <- reshape(xx, timevar=1, varying=2:28, direction="long", sep="") ```, as it has 28 columns. There are no missing values.

Comment: @Julia I don't know, you may want to consult this highly active question to learn how to reshape data from wide to long: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/6574038